# how to do this for all emulators

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="365dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_border" >
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/contactimg"
            style="@style/CodeFont"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_border_imageview"
            android:maxHeight="75dp"
            android:maxWidth="75dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:textSize="15dp" >
        </ImageButton>

</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:weightSum="1" 
                android:background="@drawable/round_border">
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView03"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Textttt"
            android:padding="10dp" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/replaymassegebutton"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_indicator"
            android:text="Reply"
            android:textColor="@color/gray2" >
        </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In HVGA emulator it'is worded fine. but in another emulator it is not. As you can see I put height=365dp,(I have to change height but I don't know how, 365dp works only in HVGA mode) what should I do here so it work for all emulator. I tried wrap_content and fill_parrent but when I set this paramteters the buttons gone (which are in another layout). I also tried this way android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="0dp". but no result here. Could you give me another solution

Comment: Need something more.... 
1. What is the parent layout? Linear, relative or what? 
2. Are buttons Going to be in bottom always? and you want this UI to cover remaining area on screen?

Edit your question... Elaborate atleast this much and add anything more you feel proper to share..... It'll make us easy to post an answer

Comment: parent layout is Linear. Buttuns always have to be in bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better have parent layout as relative.

1. there you can put buttons always at bottom- by setting `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in your property of button [or buttons manager in case there are more than one buttons]...
2. For the remaining screen you may have to use `LinearLayout` there, use it as an immidiate child and arrange your original view there.... make it `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and put your buttons view below it... by adding this `android:layout_below=` to button view.. this will make your linear layout to acquire all remaining space that has not taken by buttons.... add scroll view as immediate child of linear layout in case of smaller screens...

and you have least worries about multiple screens....

Enjoy